# Animated TV show with magic gloves

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

So there was this show that used to be on Netflix and I can't for the life of me remember the name. It was one of those weird kinds of early-2000s shows I think. (Similar to things like *Huntik* and *Spider Riders* in vibe but more *Huntik*.)

I only remember a few things about it one of which was I think there was some group of magical heroes or something and eventually they had the twist that the main character's mom used to be one. We find out by seeing her having their signature weird glove thing, hers was green I think and all wooden?

I think there was some weird episode in an icy terrain where they had the group female character face off against this weird eye thing I think?

I don't know if this WAS *Huntik*, because I can't finish that show, or if it was something else or if I just dreamt it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be thinking of ***[Kaijudo](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2339980/)*** (2012–2013).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaijudo):

> *Kaijudo* is a 2012 American animated series and trading card game that serve as a spin-off and relaunch of the Japanese Duel Masters franchise. The animated series was produced by Hasbro Studios, animated by Moi Animation in South Korea, and developed by Henry Gilroy and Andrew R. Robinson for Wizards of the Coast.

> The series follows the adventures of a teenage boy named Ray Okamoto from San Campion who possesses the rare ability to summon and duel alongside fantastical creatures from a parallel dimension. Ray and his two best friends Allie and Gabe join the ranks of the mysterious Duel Masters to ensure the survival of both races.

The main characters in the show use gloves to summon monsters, and it's eventually revealed that the main character's mother, Janet Pierce-Okamoto, has one of these gloves herself, which turns green when activated.

From the [Kaijudo Wiki](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Janet_Pierce-Okamoto):

> In episode 24, Janet reveals to Raiden that his father was a Duel Master who taught her how to duel. During a fight in episode 24, Janet puts on her gauntlet to summon a creature, but is unable to do so, because The Choten activated a summoning inhibiter.

You can see her put on the glove at around the 6:43 mark in the video below.

Comment: It might have been but I don't think so I kinda remember specifically them finding the mom's glove like in a box of things or something

Comment: @Janus - Her son finds the glove in a shoe box earlier in the video I linked to, around the [1:20](https://youtu.be/901qXktWwkQ?t=80) mark.